# Does C# have an equivalent of Java static nested class?

Tags: c#, java, static, class, nested

I am converting Java into C# and have the following code (see [discussion in Java Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581931/should-i-refactor-static-nested-classes-in-java-into-separate-classes) about its use). One approach might be to create a separate file/class but is there a C# idom which preserves the intention in the Java code?

```
   public class Foo {

    // Foo fields and functions
    // ...
        private static class SGroup {
            private static Map<Integer, SGroup> idMap = new HashMap<Integer, SGroup>();

            public SGroup(int id, String type) {
    // ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a look
http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/01/685248.aspx

I am looking specifically at

> In other words, Java inner classes are
>   syntactic sugar that is not available
>   to C#. In C#, you have to do it
>   manually.
>
> If you want, you can create your own
>   sugar:
>
> ```
> class OuterClass {
>  ...
>  InnerClass NewInnerClass() {
>   return new InnerClass(this);
>  }
>  void SomeFunction() {
>   InnerClass i = this.NewInnerClass();
>   i.GetOuterString();
>  }
> }
> ```
>
> Where you would want to write in Java
>   new o.InnerClass(...) you can write in
>   C# either o.NewInnerClass(...) or new
>   InnerClass(o, ...). Yes, it's just a
>   bunch of moving the word new around.
>   Like I said, it's just sugar.

Comment: The blog is useful and shows that the construct can lead to some ugly syntax.

Comment: Java's static nested class is just for scoping mechanism. Java's static nested class translates directly to C#'s: `class Foo { class Group { } }`. This is not the correct answer, choose @JonSkeet answer

Answer (score 90):

*All* C# nested classes are like Java static nested classes:

C#:

```
class Outer
{
    class Inner
    {
    }
}
```

Is like Java's:

```
class Outer
{
    static class Inner
    {
    }
}
```

In other words, an instance of `Inner` **doesn't have** an implicit reference to an instance of `Outer`.

There *isn't* the equivalent of a Java *inner* class in C# though.

The accessibility rules are somewhat different between the two languages though: in C#, the code in the nested class has access to private members in the containing class; in Java all code declared within one top-level type has access to all the other private members declared within that same top-level type.

Comment: I think you mean all *non-static* C# nested classes are like Java static nested classes?

Comment: @Mishax: Well, static classes in C# have no equivalent in Java, whether they're top-level or nested.

Comment: That is true! My point is you emphasized the "All" in your answer and I think the statement "All C# nested classes are like Java static nested classes" is false

Comment: Perfect answer, except for one thing: _"In C#, the code in the nested class has access to private members in the containing class; in Java it's the other way round."_ ... In Java, it is not the other way round, but both ways: In Java, the containing class has access to the nested class' private members, and the nested class has access to the conaining class' private members.

Answer (score -2):

You can have a static nested class in C#, according to [Nested Classes](http://en.csharp-online.net/Nested_Classes).