# Jackson incorrectly deserializing nested object's values into parent

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following JSON file which I am trying to deserialize:

```
{
    "name": "ComponentX",
    "implements": ["Temperature.Sensor"],
    "requires": [
        {"type": "interface", "name": "Temperature.Thermostat", "execute": [
            "../Thermostat.exe"
        ]}
    ]
}
```

It is a description of a component in a code sample for a distributed system.

Here is the class that this is supposed to deserialize to:

```
public class ComponentDescription {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String Name;

    @JsonProperty("implements")
    public String[] Implements;

    @JsonProperty("requires")
    public ComponentDependency[] Requires;

    @JsonIgnore
    public String RabbitConnectionName;

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static ComponentDescription FromJSON(String json)
        throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
        return mapper.readValue(json, ComponentDescription.class);
    }

    public class ComponentDependency
    {
        @JsonCreator
        public ComponentDependency() {
            // Need an explicit default constructor in order to use Jackson.
        }

        @JsonProperty("type")
        public DependencyType Type;

        @JsonProperty("name")
        public String Name;

        /**
         * A list of ways to start the required component if it is not already running.
         */
        @JsonProperty("execute")
        public String[] Execute;
    }

    /**
     * A dependency can either be on "some implementation of an interface" or it
     * can be "a specific component", regardless of what other interface implementations
     * may be available.
     */
    public enum DependencyType
    {
        Interface,
        Component
    }
}
```

When I run `ComponentDescription.FromJSON(jsonData)`, which uses the Jackson ObjectMapper to deserialize the JSON into the appropriate classes, I get the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "type" (class edu.umd.cs.seam.dispatch.ComponentDescription), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: , "implements", "name", "requires"])
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@39346e64; line: 1, column: 103] (through reference chain: edu.umd.cs.seam.dispatch.ComponentDescription["requires"]->edu.umd.cs.seam.dispatch.ComponentDescription["type"])
```

It seems that Jackson is trying to deserialize the `requires` array in the JSON object as an array of `ComponentDescription` instead of an array of `ComponentDependency`.  **How do I get it to use the correct class?** I would prefer an answer that gets Jackson to look at the type of `public ComponentDependency[] Requires` and see use it automatically over an answer that requires me to put the type name in again somewhere else (such as an `@` attribute).

Comment: I should note that I'm used to Newtonsoft JSON.net, where this exact example works flawlessly.  I need to write the same library in multiple languages, and I would like the code to be as close as possible in all of them to the original in C# for easier future maintenance (though I recognize that this is not always possible).

Comment: Why isn't your `ComponentDependency` class `static`? And why isnt' the `required` member a `List` (same goes for `Implements`)? Note: you should use lowercase letters for instance member names and methods, it is too easy to mix them with class names otherwise

Comment: @fge I'm using ProperCase (for now) because I'm trying to keep the interface the same as the existing C# version (where the standard is to use ProperCase) while I work out the bugs.  Once I'm ready to release it, I'm going to fix those things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the problem comes from `ComponentDependency` not being `static`. As it is not declared `static`, it means it can only be instantiated with an existing instance of `ComponentDescription`.

For more details, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581977/does-c-sharp-have-an-equivalent-of-java-static-nested-class/1581989#1581989).

Comment: Thanks!  You can tell I'm used to the C# way in the answer you linked to.